# Suppose that $A$ be a square, invertible matrix such that $A^{4} = A$. Find all real eigenvalues of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ be a square, invertible matrix such that $A^4=A$. Find all real eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: What have you thought about so far to solve this problem?

Comment: How can you use invertibility of $A$ at least?

Comment: I tried to show that Ax= bx for b is eigenvalue of A. Then since A^4 = A, I have A^4 x = bx, then fourth root both sides. Ax = 4th root of b.x. So 4th root of b is eigenvalue of A. Keep going I have 4n root of b is eigenvalue of A. But I dont know is that right or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since

$A^4 = A, \tag{1}$

we have

$A(A^3 - I) = A^4 - A = 0, \tag{2}$

and since $A$ is invertible we may write

$A^3 - I = I(A^3 - I) = (A^{-1}A)(A^3 - I)$
$= A^{-1}(A(A^3 - I)) = A^{-1}(A^4 - A) = 0; \tag{3}$

now if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ there is a vector $v \ne 0$ such that

$Av = \lambda v, \tag{4}$

whence

$A^2v = A(Av) = A(\lambda v) = \lambda(Av)$
$= \lambda(\lambda v) = \lambda^2 v; \tag{5}$

likewise

$A^3 v = A(A^2 v) = A(\lambda^2 v)$
$= \lambda^2(Av) = \lambda^2 (\lambda v) =\lambda^3 v;.\tag{6}$

combining (6) with (3) we find

$(\lambda^3 - 1)v = \lambda^3 v - v = A^3 v - Iv$
$=  (A^3 - I)v = 0, \tag{7}$

and since $v \ne 0$ we conclude that

$\lambda^3 - 1 = 0 \tag{8}$

for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$; the eigenvalues must then lie among the roots of the polynomial $\lambda^3 - 1$, and since

$(\lambda - 1)(\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1) = \lambda^3 - 1 = 0, \tag{9}$

we see that either $\lambda = 1$ or

$\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1 = 0; \tag{10}$

by the quadratic formula, the roots of (10) are

$\lambda = \dfrac{1}{2}(-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}); \tag{11}$

we thus conclude that *the only possible real eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$*.

The question remains, is $1$ *necessarily* an eigenvalue of $A$?  The answer is "no";  to see this, observe that

$(A - I)(A^2 + A + I) = A^3 - I = 0; \tag{12}$

if now there exists a vector $y$ such that

$z = (A^2 + A + I)y \ne 0, \tag{13}$

then

$(A - I)z = (A - I)(A^2 + A + I)y$
$=  (A^3 - I)y = 0, \tag{14}$

that is,

$Az = z; \tag{15}$

$1$ is in fact an eigenvalue in this case; the other option is

$(A^2 + A + I)y = 0 \tag{16}$

for all $y$, or

$A^2 + A + I = 0; \tag{17}$

certainly such matrices exist; an example is

$A = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}. \tag{18}$

The final conclusion is thus

$1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $A^2 + A + I \ne 0$, and no other real eigenvalues are possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Starting point*:  If $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$, then

- $A \mathbf{v}=\lambda \mathbf{v}$, which implies $A^4 \mathbf{v}=\lambda^4 \mathbf{v}$.

But the question also tells us that:

- $A^4 \mathbf{v}=A \mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$.

What does this tell us about the real number $\lambda$?

(The other tool required is the lemma:  $A$ is not invertible if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.)

Comment: I did try to combine all of those ideas before asking thing question, but I still have no way to get the make-sence answer.

Comment: We have $\lambda^4 \mathbf{v} = A^4 \mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$.  Since $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$, some coordinate of $\mathbf{v}$ is non-zero, $c$ say, and consequently we have $\lambda^4 c=\lambda c$.  Now, $c$ is going to be some real number (or maybe complex number; it wasn't specified in the question), so we can divide both sides of $\lambda^4 c=\lambda c$ by $c$.

Comment: Is that $\lambda = 1$ ?

Comment: Kind of.  We find $\lambda^4=\lambda$, and the only real numbers that satisfy that are $0$ and $1$ (as $4$ is even).

Comment: Since $A^4 = A$, I can get $A=A^{1+3n}$ . Then I got stuck

Comment: Are you confused about how $A \mathbf{v}=\lambda \mathbf{v}$ implies $A^4 \mathbf{v}=\lambda^4 \mathbf{v}$?  It follows like this $A^4 \mathbf{v}=A^3(A \mathbf{v})=A^3(\lambda \mathbf{v})=\lambda A^3 \mathbf{v}=\lambda A^2(A \mathbf{v})=\lambda A^2(\lambda \mathbf{v})=\lambda^2 A^2\mathbf{v}=\cdots=\lambda^4 \mathbf{v}$?

Comment: Since $A^4 = A$, I can get $A=A^{1+3n}$ . Then I got stuck since with your suggestion, I should get $\lambda ^{1+3n} = \lambda$. Then $\lambda ^{3n} = 1$ since $\lambda $ can't equal 0

Comment: I understand what you are trying to show me. However, what if $A^4 v = A^3 (Av) = A^3 (A^4 v) = A^7 v$ and so on?

Comment: You've lost me.  You should be trying to decrease the exponent by using $A \mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$.

Comment: So $\lambda = 1 $ or $0$, but since A is invertible, $\lambda$ can't be 0. Thus $\lambda=1$? How about if I say, $A=A^4=A^3 A=A^3 A^4 =A^7$ that make $\lambda ^7 v=\lambda v$. Thus $\lambda = 0,1,-1$ ??? I'm getting lost now

Comment: While it's true that $\lambda^7=\lambda$, and this indeed implies $\lambda \in \{0,1,-1\}$, we get an even stronger condition using $\lambda^4=\lambda$, i.e., that $\lambda \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: I think I got it. So since A is invertible as hypothesis, $\lambda$ can't be 0. Thus $\lambda={1}. Thank you.